# rails - redirect back unless previous page was artist page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, controller

I'd like to redirect back to the previous page, UNLESS the previous page was my 'artist' controller's 'show' action.

So I guess it would look something like:

```
if *previous page was artist show*
  redirect_to [track.artist, track]
else
  redirect_to :back
end
```

My question is - how do I test if the previous page was my artist controller's show action..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps `request.referer` is what you're looking for? Then you can say something like:

```
if request.referer == artist_url(track.artist)
  redirect_to [track.artist, track]
else
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: hmm - seems like a good idea, but for some reason that's not working.  For some reason it's failing the test (so it keeps redirecting :back as opposed to the artist, track page).  Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Sorry I think it should be artist_url and not artist_path. I will update the answer. You will also have to bear in mind that any params might not match so you could use a regex to check this.