# Redirection based on the current controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have two views that are using the `users#create` action: `users/new.thml.erb` and `enter_email.html.erb`.

The problem is that with the current code, the user is redirected to `new.html.erb` when the 
form in `enter_email.html.erb` has a validation error. So I tried this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      if params[:action] == "enter_email"
        render 'enter_email'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

I wanted to user to be redirected to `enter_email.html.erb` when the action is 'enter_email'. But I'm still being redirected to 'new.html.erb'.

Any suggestions to fix this? (it is because the action being performed is actually `create`? If so, how to modify the code to make the redirection work?)

Comment: Looks like the `params[:action]` is something other than "enter_email". What's in your params hash? You can add `raise params.to_yaml` to the top of your `create` method to find out.

Comment: @bevanb this? `Users#enter_email` or this? `controller: users
action: enter_email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of ways to do it:

- Add a hidden field to both forms, and check in `params` for the value of that field, so you know which form you come from

  ```
  # in your new.html.erb view
  hidden_field_tag 'form_name', 'new'

  # in your enter_email.html.erb view
  ```

  hidden_field_tag 'form_name', 'enter_email'

  ```
  # in controller
  if params[:form_name] == "enter_email"
    render 'enter_email'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
  ```
- Use a different action for creation, like `create_from_enter_email`, and direct the `enter_email` form to it.

Comment: +1. What I suggested was the easiest to implement, but I had considered also mentioning the first of these two.

Comment: @rewritten thanks they are good solutions but aren't them a little bit hacky?

Comment: @alexchenco I don't think so, see the edited answer for example code. Hidden fields are used all the way, for checking UTF-8 support in field content, CSRF tokens etc.

Comment: @rewritten thanks I'll try that once I come back home and check your answer.

Comment: By the way, why did you prefer hidden_field_tag over : hidden_field?

Comment: Well, I think that `f.hidden_field` would add an entry to your `params[:user]` data, you don't want it in the user, right?

Comment: @rewritten Thanks the redirects is working now. Too bad there is another problem now: when the field is submitted and there is an error the params are no longer there (no longer in the URL). So, the form fails all the validations (name, email, password), ha. But I guess that's another question.

Answer (score 2):

As you thought, the problem is that the action is `create` and not `enter_email`, so the if/else conditional always goes to the else branch and the `new` view is rendered.

To render the previous view, you can use `request.referrer` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877093/rails-redirect-back-unless-previous-page-was-artist-page):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    if request.referrer == root_url
      render 'enter_email'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

I'm checking if `request.referrer` is `root_url` based on the fact that the login partial is on the homepage (which you mention in the comments below). This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting this: `undefined local variable or method `enter_email_user_url' for #<UsersController:0xb35af24>
`

Comment: What's the route for the `enter_email` view?

Comment: here it is: `match '/enter_email', to: 'users#enter_email'` But it is still sending me to the `new.html.erb`. Strange.

Comment: Oh then try changing `enter_email_user_url` to `enter_email_url`.

Comment: I did that but now I'm being redirected to the `new` form.

Comment: Can you add a `puts request.referrer` above the if/else conditional and see what it gives you?

Comment: Ha I did that and I can't find the output. Where should it be?

Comment: Oh I see, so the `enter_email.html.erb` is on the homepage? Then you should be checking: `if request.referrer == root_url`.

Comment: Referrer can't be trusted, as it's in complete control of the client. Use separate actions (read: methods), and factor out the common code in another method.

Comment: @rewritten then post that as an answer!

Comment: ok, it was just a comment to your answer, in fact I'd do it in a completely different way...

Comment: @shioyama no is not the homepage

Comment: @alexchenco well whatever view is at the root (`/`) of your app then?